# Add variable link at JSON structure

Tags: php, json

I want to add link : https://xxx.xxx/posters/poster.jpg from JSON response, here my code :

```
/**
 * Get all movies
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getAllMovies()
{
    $movieQuery = DB::select('
                  SELECT
                  movies.m_poster AS poster,
                  movies.m_backdrop AS backdrop,
                  FROM movies
                  WHERE movies.show <> 0 AND movies.m_age <> "G"
                  GROUP BY movies.created_at,movies.m_id DESC
                  LIMIT 100');

    // Check if there is no movies
    if (empty($movieQuery)) {
        $movieQuery = null;
    }
```

And here's JSON response :

```
        .....
        "poster": "04e33bbc8cdb8f09f6991acc7956dcae.jpg",
        "backdrop": "e3324cdb3cc03fe332e3cb233aae9c77.jpg",
        .....
```

How to make it something like this :

```
              ......
                "poster": "https://xxx.xxx/posters/04e33bbc8cdb8f09f6991acc7956dcae.jpg",
                "backdrop": "https://xxx.xxx/backdrop/e3324cdb3cc03fe332e3cb233aae9c77.jpg",
             ......
```

Comment: Do you want to run anything to iterate over the returned `$movieQuery` fields or do you want it in the SQL query itself?

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over them  and add the url to the beginning of the value:

```
foreach ($json as $key => &$value) 
    $value = "https://xxx.xxx/$key/$value";
```

Comment: One tiny issue, though: the key is `poster` while the url part is `posters`.

Comment: @El_Vanja I see, if the key is not the same in the url, then OP should come up with a mapping method.

Comment: Agreed. Just wanted to point it out (both for the OP and whoever might come across this in the future).

Comment: @El_Vanja much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL there's the function [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) which could be used like the following:

```php
$movieQuery = DB::select('
                  SELECT
                  CONCAT("https://xxx.xxx/posters/", movies.m_poster) AS poster,
                  CONCAT("https://xxx.xxx/backdrop/", movies.m_backdrop) AS backdrop,
                  FROM movies
                  WHERE movies.show <> 0 AND movies.m_age <> "G"
                  GROUP BY movies.created_at,movies.m_id DESC
                  LIMIT 100');
```

The other method posted by Amir MB above would work if you want to iterate over them before displaying to the screen.

Comment: @AmirMB I like that we both provided good answers. I would lean towards my way if the movie database is expected to grow. That way you aren't going through a long foreach to append data. OR better would be on the presentation side to put the URLs.

Comment: Yes that make sense, my response is for the time that you don't have access to the source of the JSON file and it is given that way.